# What is the process to clone a repo and recreate the python virtual enviroment using the pipenv.lock file?

Tags: python, pipenv

What is the process to clone a repo and recreate the python virtual environment using the pipenv.lock file?

On my development system, I created a virtual environment using pyenv and pipenv , and am ready to test my code on another system. I've installed pyenv/pipenv/python(same version as dev machine) on the test system, but I don't how to tell pipenv to create an identical virtual environment on the test system using the content of the version-controller Pipfile.lock file.
do I do 'pipenv install --python '? 
or just 'pipenv install' and it will find and read the .lock file?

```sh
pipenv install --python <version> 
pipenv install
```

I expect a virtual environment with all of the requirements/dependencies specified in the lock file to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/) it's just:

```
pipenv install --ignore-pipfile
```

> This tells Pipenv to ignore the Pipfile for installation and use what’s in the Pipfile.lock. Given this Pipfile.lock, Pipenv will create the exact same environment you had when you ran pipenv lock, sub-dependencies and all.